# Memory Error, nil passed to a callee that requires a non-null first parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nativescript, material-components-ios

I have created an application that are readily to be published on Apple Store and the application already ran on build, but when i clicked the "Analyze" under "Product Tab" on XCode it generates an error on `selectedViewController`.

[MDCTabViewController Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqt1f.png)

Does this error subjected for rejection on Apple Store?

Comment: Maybe not. Our app has memory error too if xcode analzying and manages to publish nativescript ios

Comment: Yes i got rejected, some errors due to Material Components I used.